# Cakephp Plugin to generate sitemap

Tags: php, cakephp, seo, sitemap

I'm using Cakephp 2.4.3 . I've read that "There are CakePHP plugins that are able to **generate sitemaps** for you. This way your sitemap.xml file will be **created dynamically** on demand and **will always be up to date**." . I've searched but all I find are from old cakephp version which is not useful as they only cause errors .

Is there still a good plugin for this?

Comment: Make your own, that is the best suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins definitely exist:

1. https://github.com/sdevore/cakephp-sitemap-plugin
2. https://github.com/smarek/Croogo-Sitemap-2.0
3. https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Seo-Plugin

Are these the old, error-causing ones? As each CakePHP site can be radically different to the next, I'm not sure a one-size-fits-all solution will exist.

If you end up writing your own sitemap implementation, it'll depend mainly on whether your site has:

- Lots of **database-driven content** with few controllers/actions (like a typical WordPress-style site)
- Lots of **controller/action driven content** (more of a web application)

In the first case, you'd want to perform finds on your content, and inject the results into an xml template like this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/masterkeedu/2008/08/26/automatically-generate-dynamic-sitemaps

For the second case, the following may help: a component I've used for development/testing, which lists all controllers and their methods:

```
<?php //File: app/Controller/Component/CtrlComponent.php
// Component rewritten for Cake2.x, original from : http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/07/21/how-to-list-all-controllers/
class CtrlComponent extends Component {
    /**
     * Return an array of Controllers and their methods.
     * The function will exclude ApplicationController methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function get() {
        $aCtrlClasses = App::objects('controller');
        foreach ($aCtrlClasses as $controller) {
            if ($controller != 'AppController') {
                // Load the controller
                App::import('Controller', str_replace('Controller', '', $controller));
                // Load its methods / actions
                $aMethods = get_class_methods($controller);
                foreach ($aMethods as $idx => $method) {
                    if ($method{0} == '_') {
                        unset($aMethods[$idx]);
                    }
                }
                // Load the ApplicationController (if there is one)
                App::import('Controller', 'AppController');
                $parentActions = get_class_methods('AppController');
                $controllers[$controller] = array_diff($aMethods, $parentActions);
            }
        }
        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

In reality, a full sitemap probably uses both methods, and you'll need to consider the difference between public and "private" areas of your site (excluding admin prefixes, for example)..